# How to have my deployed application securely encrypt a password and then decrypt it later for automation use

Tags: security, encryption, hash, password-protection

This question has been answered before but the key difference may be that I want to be able to decrypt the password later on and that this is for a deployed application where someone could get a handle on the code assemblies (as opposed to a website behind a firewall)

Basically, I want my application, when deployed, to accept a user password. I want to store that user password somewhere (encrypted) and then decrypt it later for use in an automation routine.

I'll make a few assumptions to simplify things. You can assume that the password in memory is secure (while it is in memory) and that a strong hasing algorithm (feel free to name the best options) is sufficient. Even so, what would prevent someone from reflecting my code and finding the hash key or technique i'm using to decrypt the password (would i even store the hashkey in the code?). I could obfuscate but my understanding is that it is still possible to read. Also, note that one way encryption is not sufficient here. I need to decrypt and use the password later on. Any ideas?

Comment: Ideas? Sure, lots. But what is your actual question?

Comment: My question is how do you do it securely with the assumptions given.. as is how do you protect the password in such a way that you can use it again without having someone reflect through your code and figure out how to decrypt the password themselves

Comment: A person is smarter than a CPU. If the CPU can get the key out, a person can do the same.

Comment: If you have a public key (PKI) package, you can encrypt the password using the public key, then decrypt it using the secret key on the remote server. This assumes that the secret key is securely stored on the deployment server, so that even if the deployment package was intercepted, the encrypted password embedded within it is still secure.

Answer (score 1):

To directly answer the question, you're looking for asymmetric encryption (not hashing which is a one-way process) if you want to encrypt then decrypt your data. The [OWASP Top 10 on Insecure Cryptographic Storage](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A7) is a good jumping off point to learn more about this.

Now to indirectly answer your question, don't do this! Passwords should be stored with a strong cryptographic hash function including a random salt (you'll see this mentioned in the OWASP link as well). If you're trying to return password ciphertext to plain text text then authenticate to other services whilst impersonating someone else, you're missing the root cause of your problem. You've not provided much info on this but it seems the question you should be asking is how you (securely) go about identity impersonation and authentication to a downstream service.

Comment: I had a feeling someone would say "Don't do this!". What about tools that save your password and then re-enter them for you - like maybe a password recovery tool where you save your passwords. Also browsers do that now. How do they solve this problem.

Comment: There are numerous client-side tools which save your password using strong asymmetric encryption such as browsers and password managers. They do this as it's the only way they can automatically log your client on to another system and in the case of password managers, you need to be able to retrieve your actual plain text password as well. I got the impression from your question that you're talking about automating authentication between two systems you've developed in which case there are other impersonation strategies out there, perhaps you can clarify the question if this isn't the case.

Comment: What I want to do is pretty much the same thing a browser or password manager does. Asymmetric encryption sounds about right. I just don't know how to do it in a way where it is difficult reflect the encryption keys.

Comment: They both work a little differently in that password managers normally require a master password whilst browser auto-login features don't. If you can challenge for the password, then your key management problem is solved otherwise you've got to deal with storing it securely which can be a bit painful.

Comment: Any ideas on how to store it securely?